# Active Directory Schema Details for a Trusted Forest

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am trying to export AD schema details for a trusted forest.
I don't have access to a domain computer of the trusted forest.
I don't have an account of a trusted forest.

I use the following command to extract attributes of my own forest.

```
$schema = Get-ADObject -SearchBase ((Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext) `
-SearchScope OneLevel -Filter * -Property objectClass, name, whenChanged,`
whenCreated,description,attributeID, isDefunct | Select-Object objectClass, name, whenCreated, whenChanged, isDefunct, `
@{name="event";expression={($_.whenCreated).Date.ToShortDateString()}} | `
Sort-Object whenCreated
```

However Get-ADObject is not working when I provide the schema partition context of the trusted domain. it gives an error like this.

**Get-ADObject : The supplied distinguishedName must belong to one of the following partition(s)...** listing the schema, configuration , domain partitions of my current forest.

I tried to use the directory services methods. But this doesn't provide us details like **whenmodified** which is required for us to understand the timeline of schema changes in the directory.
**Any one can provide us with a comprehensive way to query schema of a trusted forest ??**

```
$Forest = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext("Forest", $ForestFQDN)
$Schema = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectorySchema]::GetSchema($Forest
$AllProperties = $Schema.FindAllProperties()
```

Comment: If you don't have credentials and the other forest does not trust the forest you are in, you will not be able to bind to a DC in the other forest.

Comment: The scenario is Forest A <--> Forest B (Two way transitive forest trust with forest-wide authentication). I have computer and user account of Forest B but I want to extract attributes and classes of Forest A. I am able to do so using the commands specified below `$Forest = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext("Forest", $ForestFQDN) $Schema = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectorySchema]::GetSchema($Forest $AllProperties = $Schema.FindAllProperties()` but not the **whenmodified** and **whencreated** fields that Get-ADobject provides.

Answer (score 1):

Info re the two-way trust would have been helpful, since a permissions issue is the first thing that comes to mind.

With your `[System.DirectoryServices]` query, you're listing the properties listed *inside* the Schema, not the Schema LDAP object properties. You've gone one level too far.

```perl
$Forest = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext("Forest", "$forestFQDN") 
$Schema = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectorySchema]::GetSchema($Forest)
$s = $Schema.GetDirectoryEntry()
$s | fl whencreated,whenchanged

whenCreated : {2002-02-06 11:40:41}
whenchanged : {2021-05-17 21:10:06}
```

If the `$Schema.GetDirectoryEntry()` method fails, it may still be a perms thing, of course. But if you can locate the object with `GetSchema`, that's encouraging.

Slightly tweaked version:

```perl
$Forest = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext("Forest", "$forestFQDN")
$ForestObj = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetForest()
$Schema = $ForestObj.Schema.GetDirectoryEntry()
```